What is this orange thing taking up half of my screen?
This transparent orange stuff keeps coming up and blocking half my screen. How do I disable it? I'm guessing it's a window snapping/workspace thing? It's popped up 3 times in the last hour without any input from me. In the screenshot my hand is off the mouse and it just stays there.
I'm able to get rid of it by dragging a window to the top of the screen.


Something similar happens to me, when I drag a window to the edge of the screen and continue dragging (it indicates that the window is to turn to full-screen). If it happens without touching the mouse or touchpad, things are too sensitive. Did you consider that your palms might activate the touchpad (if you have a laptop)?

I have this as well, it's a bug, it's supposed to show you how the window would be resized if you were lo let go of the left mouse button while dragging the window to the top edge, however it sometimes stay there (and apparently it also shows up completely unsolicited in your case; I never paied enough attention to understand exactly what triggers the "stuck" behavior, but yeah, I've had this as well a few times since updating to 24.04).

I have this too. To remove it just for that time, move a window that is not maximized a bit.

I'm not using a touch pad. It only started happening when I fresh installed 24.04 LTS. Is there any way to turn off the resizing animation? What even is the language to describe it? Resize snapping?

This seems the related bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-shell-extension-tiling-assistant/+bug/2063970
Fix is committed already but it's not resolved yet.

This is an issue with the tilling. For now, you can disable Enhanced Tiling in your Settings → Ubuntu Desktop:

After that restart the computer. When the bug is fixed you can turn them back on.
Here are two relevant bug reports:

System automatically tilling windows.

Click on the top bar invokes the enhanced tiling on maximized windows


You should enter your info in the bug reports for two reasons: first you will get an email when something happens in the bug report and second you will increase the pressure to solve the issue faster.
You can read more about what happens when you subscribe to a bug in Bugs/Subscriptions.
Update:
The bug seems to have been fixed. Read the latest changes in Click on the topbar invokes the enhanced tiling on maximized windows and update. Once the tiling is updated if you wish to have it, turn it back on.

I have two monitors and my workflow doesn't realise much utility from tiling. I knew what it was just not the nomenclature. When you say it didn't disable tiling for you, is that just after a restart?

amar's solution has worked for the last couple of days. I'll get back if it issue comes back. Cheers!

Ok, I think I figured this out, they're just two different things, and apparently the problem is with the tiling assistant extension, not with the mutter implementation; sorry for the confusion, assuming the bug is in the tiling assistant extension then this should work. I still mantain rebooting shouldn't be necessary, and reloading GNOME should be enough. +1

Bug is now fixed in "gnome-shell-extension-tiling-assistant - 46-1ubuntu1.1"
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-shell-extension-tiling-assistant/+bug/2064646/comments/15

I just got rid of it by enlarging a window to fullscreen via Super+Arrowup.

Thanks, worked like a charm

Very much have this, and it's seemingly something that undocks your window (Brave here) when you're not trying to do that... When you redock, it persists over the top.. A ctrl+tab to another app seems to fix, but equally, at super up,then left, then right brings the tab list... Perhaps that's a new feature, but the orange stuff is not a 24.* related issue...

For me going full screen and back (F11) in Firefox (didn't try other applications) solved this problem.

I simply clicked on the top-most menu bar (the black one, that has the time in the middle i.e. Fri Jul 26 2:37PM) and the translucent orange rectangle dissapeared.
