24.04 half desktop selected with red tint square
Installed fresh OS, during my work half screen is selected with red/orange tint. It looks like some default screenshot program turning on randomly or something like this. This functionality maybe mapped by default on popular key, but I could guess which one.
Please help to identify what kind of functionality is, and optionally completely turn it off
how it looks on small crop

Here is a similar problem and a solution: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1512152/what-is-this-orange-thing-taking-up-half-of-my-screen

yep, this is probably duplicate,
fixed with
gnome-extensions disable tiling-assistant@ubuntu.com

@chro maybe you can answer yourself the question in a comment below for more visibility of the answer

Does this answer your question? What is this orange thing taking up half of my screen?

As discussed in another question it needs to disable Enhanced Tiling in your Settings, Ubuntu Desktop or
gnome-extensions disable tiling-assistant@ubuntu.com
in the terminal.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

I've got the same problem now and for me going full screen and back (F11) in Firefox solved this problem.

This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - From Review
